# Is ipairs reliable on unsorted arrays?

Tags: loops, lua, iteration, lua-table

I'm wondering if anyone can confirm whether you can trust `ipairs()` to; return all indices in order, for a table that's index-complete but unsorted.

We have code all over our project that clones tables using `pairs()`, however any arrays cloned come out unordered. I'm not sure if this is a problem however.

Compare:

```
A = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}
```

to:

```
B = {[1] = 10, [2] = 20, [3] = 30, [4] = 40, [5] = 50, [6] = 60}
```

If you loop these with `pairs()`, the first one is ordered while the other is not. (On a side note, `B` is suddenly sorted if you do a couple of back inserts)

Back to the original question. It seems `B` above iterates all values in order using `ipairs()`, but is this always guaranteed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A Lua table has no order.

It is simply a set of non-`nil` keys, each associated with a single non-`nil` value.

---

Implementations do optimize the storage of "number"-typed keys with positive integer values beginning at 1 and ending at a point their choosing, growing and shrinking internal structures with time-memory trade-offs for the various table operations.

`pairs` operates on all the key-value pairs in a table.

`ipairs` operates on a conceptual sequence of contiguous positive integer-valued keys with 1 and ending just before the first `nil` value. Other key-value pairs are ignored. *So, your answer is "Yes, by design" as long as your idea of "index-complete" matches.*

`table.sort` does the same. Other key-value pairs are ignored.

The default table length operator (`#`) is more restrictive. It operates on tables that have a "sequence", which are tables with no "number"-typed keys with positive integer values (an empty sequence) or all of their "number"-typed keys with positive integer values are a contiguous sequence, starting at 1. If you use the default table length operator on a non-sequence, you get undefined behavior.

Comment: Great explanation. If I understand you correctly; it's because of the Lua implementation I use, that `A = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}` end up ordered when looping with `pairs()`. But is not part of the standard.

Comment: @CalvinE, the traversal order may change when you run the program again, if you're running Lua 5.2.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, it will.

`ipairs()` will iterates from index `1` to `n` continuously, and break in the first index which is not continuously.

For example:

```
B = {[1] = 10, [2] = 20, [3] = 30, [4] = 40, [5] = 50, [6] = 60}    

for i,v in ipairs(B) do
    print(i,v)
end

will print:
1   10
2   20
3   30
4   40
5   50
6   60
```

But,

```
B = {[1] = 10, [2] = 20, [3] = 30, [5] = 40, [6] = 50, [7] = 60}    

for i,v in ipairs(B) do
    print(i,v)
end

will print
1   10
2   20
3   30
```

Because `1,2,3` is continuously, but break in `4`, so `ipairs` stop.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's guaranteed that `ipairs` iterate a table with integer keys from `1` in order. Whether the table is sorted doesn't matter.

From [Reference Manual: `ipairs`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-ipairs):

> ```
> for i,v in ipairs(t) do body end
> ```
>
> will iterate over the pairs (`1`,`t[1]`), (`2`,`t[2]`), ..., up to the first integer key absent from the table.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, exactly what I was looking for. Though Tom's elaboration on implementations gave me a deeper understanding and earned the "solution" this time.